# How to call callback function of jquery html() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-dialog

Below is my jquery code which do following thing:

1. Load the content form URL and fill into DIV.
2. Bind the data into html form.
   Problem: first time, it bind correct data and after each call, it just load the empty form  (and data not populated which called through `BindForm` function as shown below.)

When I tried replace - tag.html with `$("#div").load(url,function(){})` then it works but, using below code not work.

Now, I can not change implementation to use `load` but, any alternative or solution in below code will helpful.

Basically, I need `$("<div id=" + diaolgID + "></div>")` line to preserve as it is and then load dialog within this.

```
var tag = $("<div id=" + diaolgID + "></div>");
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        var htmlContainerObject = tag.html(data);

        htmlContainerObject.dialog({
            modal: true,
            hide: {
                effect: "none",
                duration: 150
            },
            show: {
                effect: "none",
                duration: 150
            },
            title: title,
            width: 950,
            height: 'auto'
        }).dialog('open');

        BindForm();
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you ever appending `tag` to the `DOM`?

Comment: no. it just opening in dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your first line to this:

```
var tag = $('<div id="' + diaolgID + '"></div>').appendTo('body');
```